# Is there any way to get HTMLcontent from given URL (if user registration is required or Api have restriction on number of hits)?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, httprequest, jsdom

I use nodejs and make promise request to given urls to get their html content
and instead to get the expected html as it appears in firefox inspect element tool, i get the message:

**"You have exceeded the daily view limit as a unregistered user"**

There is any way to get HTMLcontent from given URL if:

**1st case**: User registration is required ?

**2nd case**: Api have restriction on number of hits ?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var requestPromise= require('request-promise');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    requestPromise("https://www......")
      .then(body => {
         const dom = new JSDOM(body);
         //dom.window.document.querySelector
         res.send(body)
      }).catch(error => {
         res.status(500).json(error);
     });
});
```

Comment: I didnt get what you want ,On exceed daily limit you want to show some html content or you dont know the API have restriction on number of hits

Comment: I want to take the html content of a url and instead to get the expected html as it appears in firefox inspect element tool, i get the message   "You have exceeded the daily view limit as a unregistered user".i dont know if user registration is required or the Api have have restriction on number of hits

Comment: In both cases you have to send your custom html or simply response of the request whatever you are getting, can you share API response or simply append in frontend